# React twiliio programmable video switch camera is not working

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I use `"twilio-video": "^2.8.0"` for building a video chat app. On mobile devices chat app should be able to switch the camera front and back.

I try something like this to the video track

```
tracks.restart({ facingMode: 'environment' })
```

But If I console log the `tracks`. There is no method called restart. Why would this happen?

[image]

Any help!

Thanks in adcanced. =)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Can you upgrade to [2.9.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-video/v/2.9.0)? I just tested with 2.8.0 and it didn't work, but 2.9.0 had the `restart` function.